# c# acces db file path

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm debugging ASP application from usb flash  (there is located project and I use MS Visual studio) I don't know how to indicate path to db file i try `string db_adres = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=J:\test.mdb";` but this is wrong path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you should prefix this kind of string with the char @

```
string db_adres = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='J:\test.mdb'";
```

or double the `\` character

```
string db_adres = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='J:\\test.mdb'";
```

The first one is called 'verbatim string', the second one is an 'escaped string'
Look here at [C# specifications 2.4.4.5 "String Literals"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)